# Natural language parsing for Arduino, where to start

Tags: nlp, arduino

For a school project I am looking into natural language programming and thinking how the concept may be applied to Arduino.

Think along the lines of a piece of software that would translate sentences like `If the analog sensor on pin 9 reads more than 2 Volts, set the duty cycle of the the servo on pin 10 to 70%.` or `If the digital sensor on pin 4 reads high, light the onboard LED for 5 seconds.` into Arduino code. I'm suspecting that doing this for basic Arduino use cases should be straightforward compared to more general applications.

Does such a thing exist for Arduino? Does it exist for any other popular high-level language, like Python or MATLAB? Could anyone recommend resources for an absolute beginner on the topic of natural language processing (more specifically, a non-CS, non-CS-background graduate student who knows his way around Python, C#, MATLAB and, obviously, Arduino)?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [nltk](http://nltk.org/) which is a library for Python.

Translate the sentence into commands using the above library and then use the commands to generate the Arduino code.

Another approach is to use firmdata which will allows you to send commands to Arduino through a serial port.